# hdf5storage.write() does not save into the given path?

Tags: python, mat, h5py

I wanna save a numpy array in Matlab 7.9 compatible file by using `hdf5storage` package, `mat_dir` is the path for saving the file into a directory, however, `hdf5storage.write()` writes the mat file into the current directory. What is the reason?

```
   matfile = {}
   matfile[u'image'] = myimage 
   hdf5storage.write(matfile, mat_dir, mat_file_name, matlab_compatible=True)
   ##mat_dir=/home/user/workspace/img/
```

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it by using another function:

```
hdf5storage.savemat(os.path.join(mat_dir, mat_file_name), {'image': myimage}, format='7.3')
```

and successfully saves in the given directory.